# Is this possible with libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to develop an Android app for my own project. I was wondering if it is possible to develop such an app using libGDX, and if not, what do I need to learn to code this? (My only experience with Android app development is through libGDX for some simple games).

I would like to make an app that displays a story beautifully. (Think text rpg, but a poem instead or short story). The user will press a button for the story/poem to advance. (Think powerpoint) There will be a simple gradient background. (The gradient needs to be able to fade to different colours) And the text should fade in and out as well.

I'll need tight control over the audio. Ideally there will be a voiceover that syncs to when the text fades in. Some parts will have sound effects, or when the user reaches the end of a paragraph, the current bgm will fade out (regardless of whether or not the song is finished), and when the user press continue to the next paragraph, a new, different bgm will fade in.

I would just like to know if it is possible to make this app through libGDX. If it is, I'll continue to learn from tutorials. Or else I'll learn whatever is necessary to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, libGDX can do this, but it's kind of overkill (unless you know libGDX already, or unless you'd want your project to run on both Android and also iOS). You could just do this with Java on Android (no game engine necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes.

---

If you have earlier LibGDX experience, it would be fairly easy to do in LibGDX.

The references required for features that you enumerated are

1. [Drawing a gradient in Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889316/drawing-a-gradient-in-libgdx)
2. [Streaming music](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Streaming-music)
3. [Sound effects](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects)
4. [Actions for fade effects](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#actions)

Hope this helps.
Good luck.